# Use PrintDialog to print specific pages (without using from-to)

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I would like to print specific pages using Windows Forms `PrintDialog`.
For example, pages I'd like to print are something like:
*1-3, 5, 7-9, 15, 21*.

Can this be achieved using regular PrintDialog? I only found that it's possible to set from and to pages.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can achieve that using regular PrintDialog. It allows only one range.

> The PrintRange property is used by the PrintDialog.when the user
>   selects a print range. The default PrintRange is AllPages. To enable
>   the user to specify a range of pages to print, the
>   PrintDialog.AllowSomePages property must be set to true. To enable the
>   user to specify the selected pages to print, the
>   PrintDialog.AllowSelection property must be set to true.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printrange?view=netframework-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.frompage?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Printing_PrinterSettings_FromPage